# How to compare the files of a Composer package's current and new version?

Tags: php, plugins, composer-php

When installing, updating or removing packages with Composer, I need to compare the files of the current version (if existing) to the files of the new one. This is needed so the project can (re-)generate some files if specific files of a package changed.

I'm creating a [Composer plugin](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/plugins.md#creating-a-plugin) for this, which allows for hooking into the corresponding Composer events:

```php
use Composer\DependencyResolver\Operation\UpdateOperation;
use Composer\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Composer\Installer\PackageEvent;
use Composer\Installer\PackageEvents;
use Composer\Plugin\PluginInterface;

class Plugin implements PluginInterface, EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            PackageEvents::POST_PACKAGE_UPDATE => 'addFilesForUpdate',
            ...
        ];
    }

    public function addFilesForUpdate(PackageEvent $event): void
    {
        $operation = $event->getOperation();

        assert($operation instanceof UpdateOperation);

        $initialPackageFiles = $this->getPackageFiles($operation->getInitialPackage());
        $targetPackageFiles = $this->getPackageFiles($operation->getTargetPackage());

        // TODO: If files were added, changed or removed, execute some action
    }

    private function getPackageFiles(): array
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In `getPackageFiles()`, I'm basically running `shell_exec("composer --working-dir=/some-tmp-dir/ require <name>:<version>")` right now. After the files exist on the disk, I can easily put them into an array (with their MD5 hash, to check if they've changed).

But there's at least one issue with that: This does not work with private repositories that need authentication. The `composer.json` generated in the temporary directory contains only a `require` with the package I passed to it.

How can this be achieved in an elegant way? There must also exist a better way than calling `shell_exec()` for that.